# How do you calculate monthly cashflows when looking at an AVERAGE annual growth rate between two years?

Tags: calculus, finance

Say someone has total cashflows of $1200$ for the financial year(FY) $2020$, they have cashflows of $1260$ for FY $2021$. ($5\%$ annual growth) How would you go back and fill in the cashflows for Jan-Dec $2021$ to where they are growing at an average annualized rate of $5\%$ and they all total $1260$?

I am assuming steady growth. I've tried pretty basic things, like assuming $\$100$ in cashflows for December $2020$, and then growing that by $100 x 1.05^{\frac{1}{12}}$ ... but this ends up totaling $1232.26$ for $2021$. If I had the December $2020$ cashflow in line with the growth trend, this would be easy. All of the monthly/annual cashflow conversion examples online just say to raise the growth rate by $1/12$.

I've figured out a complicated work around. Going back to a hypothetical year $1$ and assuming $\$100$ for December. Then growing monthly by $1.05^{1/12}$ ... this ends up giving $105$ for Dec year $2$. I can then find the ratio for $105$ over the sum of the year 2 cashflows. $105/1232.25775 = 0.08521...$ I can then use that to get at the Dec $2020$ theoretical cashflow by multiplying it by $1200$... It gives $102.25$... Then if I grow this over the next year, it gives me the correct answer of $1260$... but that seems overly complicated. There has to be a formula for figuring this out right?

Comment: What have you tried? Are you assuming steady growth with no seasonal effects?

Comment: Thank you for responding! Yes, I am assuming steady growth. I've tried pretty basic things, like assuming $100 in cashflows for December 2020, and then growing that by 100 x 1.05^(1/12) ... but this ends up totaling 1232.26 for 2021. If I had the December 2020 cashflow in line with the growth trend, this would be easy. All of the monthly/annual cashflow conversion examples online just say to raise the growth rate by 1/12

Comment: Start with an assumed figure for the *first* month of the first financial year and do your $\times 1.05^{1/12}$ thing each month.  That will probably give you a wrong total for the sums for each year, but you can find you need to scale both by the same multiplicative factor to get the right sums.  Apply this same multiplicative factor to *first* month of the first financial year, redo your $\times 1.05^{1/12}$ thing, and then decide whether that gives you a satisfactory answer.

Comment: I've figured out a complicated work around. Going back to a hypothetical year 1 and assuming $100 for December. Then growing monthly by 1.05^(1/12) ... this ends up giving 105 for Dec year 2. I can then find the ratio for 105 over the sum of the year 2 cashflows. 105/1232.25775 = 0.08521... I can then use that to get at the Dec 2020 theoretical cashflow by multiplying it by 1200... It gives 102.25... Then if I grow this over the next year, it gives me the correct answer of 1260... but that seems overly complicated. There has to be a formula for figuring this out right?

Comment: That is probably faster than the time it would take you to memorise a formula. I will give such a formula in an answer

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume the months are numbered $0,1,2,\ldots,23$.  If your inital month has an amount of $k$ and you want each month to be $r=1.05^{1/12}\approx 1.004074$ times the previous month, then each month you have $kr^n$ and in the first year you get $$k+kr+kr^2+\cdots +kr^{11}= k\frac{r^{12}-1}{r-1} \approx k \times 12.27258$$  so setting this equal to $1200$ gives $k \approx 97.779$, or equivalently in the second year $$kr^{12}+kr^{13}+kr^{14}+\cdots +kr^{23}= k\frac{r^{24}-r^{12}}{r-1} \approx k \times 12.88621$$  so setting this equal to $1260$ again gives $k \approx 97.779$. The final month of your first financial year would be $kr^{11} \approx 102.251$, as you have found.  So if you must have a formula for each month, it would be $kr^n = 1200\frac{1.05^{1/12}-1}{1.05-1}1.05^{n/12}$ using months numbered $0,1,2,\ldots,23$

Comment: This is awesome! Thanks Henry... I would give all of the stars and upvotes if I could.

Comment: @mcuser You can accept the answer if you wish (the tick on the top left of the answer) or wait to see if anybody else replies